# Map() returns array items multiple times - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I'm new in react and I'm trying to get a json that contains an array of objects (sent by an API REST)

This is the json I'm getting from the API

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id_pelicula": 1,
            "Nombre_pelicula": "Nocturnal Animals",
            "anio_estreno": "2016",
            "url_poster": "https://cdn.abicart.com/shop/16575/art75/h2859/177222859-origpic-9d7682.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id_pelicula": 2,
            "Nombre_pelicula": "Prisoners",
            "anio_estreno": "2013",
            "url_poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg0NTIzMjQ1NV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDc3MzM5OQ@@._V1_.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the code of my component:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const PeliCard = () => {
  const [peliculas, setPeliculas] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/getPeliculas").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setPeliculas(response.data.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="col animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
      <div className="col-4">
        {peliculas.map((pelicula, index) => (
          <img key={index} src={pelicula.url_poster} className="card-img" />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I run the app, it shows the elements of the array multiple times, when it only should show 2 elements.

[image]

How could I solve it? thanks in advance

Comment: There is no apparent sign in your `PeliCard` component that there is something wrong. How is the `PeliCard` component being implemented?

Comment: Each pelicard displays all of the movies.  So if you have like 6 pelicards being shown you'd get what you describe.